# Why is Netbean's interface showing up in a bunch of nonsensical characters?

Tags: java, netbeans

So I installed the newest Netbeans yesterday after not having used it for awhile, and when I got it open, the whole interface (menus and context menus) are all coming up in nonsense!

[image]

I've tried reinstalling Netbeans, and also adding "--locale enUS" to the target path, but I just can't get the menus to come up in English. Also, it's not like I can navigate the options to try to change anything because even if I do get to them, they are all gargled as well!

Does anybody know what I should do here?! It's really setting me back in my work!

Comment: Looks like one of the fonts on your Win10 system got thoroughly screwed up. Obviously the font used for NetBeans' menus and dialogs. But I could be wrong.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. I had recently changed my system font. But any idea which font exactly I'd need to change to affect the Netbeans UI?

Comment: Nope, sorry. Just take a look in the fonts directory which font loks suspicious. It should show in the Explorer, IIRC. I am writing this on an iPad, so I can't check right now.

Answer (score 0):

I looked around and found an answer! I just added `-J-Dswing.aatext=true -J-Dawt.useSystemAAFontSettings=lcd --laf Metal` to the config, and now I'm in business!